# How do I insert the following code to format the date time before I export to excel?

Tags: reactjs, excel, datetime

I would like to insert the code below

```
const dateStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleDateString(
        "en-CA"
      );
      const timeStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleTimeString();
      const dateTime = `${dateStr} ${timeStr}`;
```

To change the data in api call/endpoint from: {"ID":3,"name":"Carlena","email":"Carlena@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":2,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-03-12T12:08:23.000Z","contacted":"Yes"},

to

{"ID":3,"name":"Carlena","email":"Carlena@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":2,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-03-12 ","contacted":"Yes"},

Before I export to csv in the code block below

```
 const DataSet = [
    {
      columns: [
        {
          title: "S/N",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 100 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Customer Information",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 250 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Customer Email",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 250 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Counts of Visit",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 175 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Latest Time of Visit",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 250 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Contacted?",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 250 },
        }, // width in pixels
      ],
      data: customerList.map((val) => [
        { value: val.ID, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.name, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.email, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.counts_of_visit, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.latest_time_of_visit, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.contacted, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
      ]),
    },
  ];
```

Any idea how to do so? Or if there is a better way to format the date after I query from my sql database api endpoint would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Just make it a function:

```
const formatDatetime = (datetime) => {
    const dateStr = new Date(datetime).toLocaleDateString(
        "en-CA"
      );
    const timeStr = new Date(datetime).toLocaleTimeString();
    return `${dateStr} ${timeStr}`;
}
```

and use it inside your map:

```
...
data: customerList.map((val) => [
        { value: val.ID, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.name, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.email, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.counts_of_visit, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: formatDatetime(val.latest_time_of_visit), style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.contacted, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
      ]),
...
```

Comment: How do I so format the data before I pull from the api endpoint /customers?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question.. You can't format the data you don't have yet; of course you can format it on backend (if you have access to its code), but then it's not a React question..

Comment: How do I format it on backend?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67758546/how-do-i-format-the-datetime-format-in-an-api-call-from-mysql